# Core Plot: How to present popover from a bar selected by the user

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-plot, uipopovercontroller

#### What I would like to accomplish

I am using Core Plot (1.1) to draw a bar chart and I would like to present a popover with further details below the bar which has been selected (tapped) by the user.

#### Code

My code looks like this:

```
- (void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {

    NSNumber *yValue = self.values[idx];
    NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: %i, y: %@",idx,yValue);

    NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
    NSNumber *plotXvalue = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                         field:CPTScatterPlotFieldX
                                   recordIndex:idx];
    plotPoint[CPTCoordinateX] =
        CPTDecimalFromFloat(plotXvalue.floatValue);

    NSNumber *plotYvalue = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                         field:CPTScatterPlotFieldY
                                   recordIndex:idx];

    plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] =
        CPTDecimalFromFloat(plotYvalue.floatValue); 

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace =
        (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    CGPoint dataPoint =
        [plotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:plotPoint];
    NSLog(@"datapoint (CGPoint) coordinates tapped: %@",
          NSStringFromCGPoint(dataPoint));

    GrowthChartInfoTableViewController *infoViewController =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
         @"GrowthChartInfo"];

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                    initWithContentViewController:infoViewController];
    self.popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 300);
    self.popover.delegate = self;
    CGRect popoverAnchor =
            CGRectMake(dataPoint.x + graph.paddingLeft,
                       dataPoint.y - graph.paddingTop + graph.paddingBottom,
                       (CGFloat)1.0f, (CGFloat)1.0f);

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverAnchor
                                  inView:self.view
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
}
```

#### My problem

The y-position of the popover view controller is incorrect, it is different for each bar and for the first bar, which has a negative y-value, it is presented at the upper limit of the bar instead the lower limit and hides the bar. The x-position seems to be correct.

[image]

#### Please help

Any ideas on why my code does not work as expected?

Thank you!

## Edit

Based on Eric's answer I have updated my code as follows:

```
- (void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {

    NSNumber *plotXvalue = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                         field:CPTScatterPlotFieldX
                                   recordIndex:idx];
    NSNumber *plotYvalue = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                         field:CPTScatterPlotFieldY
                                   recordIndex:idx];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    CGPoint cgPlotPoint =
        CGPointMake(plotXvalue.floatValue,
                    plotYvalue.floatValue);
    CGPoint cgPlotAreaPoint =
        [graph convertPoint:cgPlotPoint toLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];

    NSDecimal plotAreaPoint[2];
    plotAreaPoint[CPTCoordinateX] =
        CPTDecimalFromFloat(cgPlotAreaPoint.x);
    plotAreaPoint[CPTCoordinateY] =
        CPTDecimalFromFloat(cgPlotAreaPoint.y);

    CGPoint dataPoint = [plotSpace


           plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:plotAreaPoint];
        NSLog(@"datapoint (CGPoint) coordinates tapped: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(dataPoint));

GrowthChartInfoTableViewController *infoViewController = [self.storyboard 
   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GrowthChartInfo"];



    self.popover = nil;
        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]


      initWithContentViewController:infoViewController];
    self.popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(250, 200);
    self.popover.delegate = self;
    CGRect popoverAnchor =
        CGRectMake(dataPoint.x + graph.paddingLeft,
                   dataPoint.y - graph.paddingTop + graph.paddingBottom,
                   (CGFloat)1.0f, (CGFloat)1.0f);

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:popoverAnchor
        inView:self.view
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
        animated:YES];
}
```

However, the results I am getting are more erroneous than before. I believe I must have misunderstand something. Here are some of the results of the NSLog commands:

```
barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: 0, y: -0.03920931548773198848
datapoint (CGPoint) coordinates tapped: {-6388.88, -67024.8}

barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: 2, y: 0.174494288286651392
datapoint (CGPoint) coordinates tapped: {-6073.38, -66790}

barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: 2, y: 0.174494288286651392
datapoint (CGPoint) coordinates tapped: {-6073.38, -66790}

barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: 0, y: -0.03920931548773198848
datapoint (CGPoint) coordinates tapped: {-6388.88, -67024.8}
```

It seems that the conversion from the bar coordinates to the view coordinates is completely wrong in my code.

### Edit 2

Thank you again for your code sample, Eric!

I have updated my code and tested it with the following options (y-value = 0: `plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f)`, which results in an anchor point for the popover whose y-value seems to be incorrect (please refer to the following screenshot). The anchor point's y-value should be equivalent to the position of `0` on the y-axis.

[image]

Then I tried to set the y-value of the anchor point to the current y-value of the data. (`plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] = plotYvalue.decimalValue`). This results in an anchor point which is close to the y-axis's 0 value instead of being close to the top of the bar. However, the y-value changes a little bit for each company (x-value) indicating that there might be a problem with the shift of the y-values:

[image]

I also tried the additional conversion which Eric suggested `dataPoint = [self.view convertPoint:dataPoint fromView:graph.hostingView]`, but this did not change the results. In addition, I tried to add `- graph.paddingTop + graph.paddingBottom` to the final y-values, without success.

I would appreciate any ideas on what my error might be.

Thank you!

Comment: Bar is not a UIComponent . Its just a drawing. So You need to create a CGRect point when you draw bar for each bar and store in array and you need to check the user touch in any of the rect in array in your touchesBegan: method. I may be wrong too. But this is just an idea.

Comment: I am using `- barPlot:barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` to get the index  of the selected bar and its y-value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:` method returns a point in the plot area coordinate system. You need to convert that to the graph's coordinate system:

```
[graph convertPoint:dataPoint fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];
```

The graph and its hosting view share a coordinate system. If `self.view` is not the hosting view, you will need to convert the coordinates to its coordinate system from the hosting view.

---

A more complete code sample:

```
NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
NSNumber *plotXvalue = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                     field:CPTScatterPlotFieldX
                               recordIndex:idx];
plotPoint[CPTCoordinateX] = plotXvalue.decimalValue;

NSNumber *plotYvalue = [self numberForPlot:plot
                                     field:CPTScatterPlotFieldY
                               recordIndex:idx];
plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] = plotYvalue.decimalValue; 

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

// convert from data coordinates to plot area coordinates
CGPoint dataPoint = [plotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:plotPoint];

// convert from plot area coordinates to graph (and hosting view) coordinates
dataPoint = [graph convertPoint:dataPoint fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];

// convert from hosting view coordinates to self.view coordinates (if needed)
dataPoint = [self.view convertPoint:dataPoint fromView:hostingView];

NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: %@, y: %@", plotXvalue, plotYvalue);
NSLog(@"datapoint coordinates tapped: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(dataPoint));
```

Comment: Do I have to convert the point using `-plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:`first and then convert it again using `[graph convertPoint:dataPoint fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea]`? When I chain these two methods, I get wrong results for the x-values. However, when I don't use `[graph convertPoint:dataPoint fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea]`I get correct x-values. How can this be?

Comment: The `-plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:` conversion is required. It takes values in data coordinates (bar location and tip) and converts them to view coordinates in the plot area.

Comment: Eric, thank you for your code sample, which I have tested extensively. However, I still have issues with the y-coordinates: It seems that there is a problem with the shift of the y-values. When I set the y-values to 0, the anchor point sticks to the top of the bars. For changing y-values (e.g. 0.15 and 0.17) the anchor point changes too, but remains close the 0 value of the y-axis. Any ideas on what could be wrong with my code? Thank you!

Comment: Core Plot applies a flip transform to the hosting view on iOS. The y-coordinate of your popover anchor is in the flipped coordinate system. You're missing another coordinate space conversion somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the **flipped coordinate system** causes the problem. However, I have absolutely no idea where I should need an additional space conversion (and how I should add it). Unfortunately, this coordinate space conversion topic is completely new to me. Do you have any hint for me on how I could resolve this issue or where I should look for the error? Thank you so much!

Comment: It's hard to offer more suggestions without knowing what all the views are and how the view hierarchy is arranged.