# Core-Plot - get coordinates of parent view from x y values

Tags: ios, ios7, core-plot

I have a scatter plot and x,y values of a point in that plot. I'd like to add information on top of the plot, but I can't seem to get the parent view coordinates from the x y values. I've got the following code from this question, but the values are not correct : [Core Plot: How to present popover from a bar selected by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658209/core-plot-how-to-present-popover-from-a-bar-selected-by-the-user/13663046)

i have a `CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;` located in a `UIView *statsView;`

```
NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
NSNumber *plotXvalue = [distanceArray objectAtIndex:index];

plotPoint[CPTCoordinateX] = plotXvalue.decimalValue;

NSNumber *plotYvalue = [altitudeArray objectAtIndex:index];
plotPoint[CPTCoordinateY] = plotYvalue.decimalValue;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.hostView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;

// convert from data coordinates to plot area coordinates
CGPoint dataPoint = [plotSpace plotAreaViewPointForPlotPoint:plotPoint numberOfCoordinates:2];

// convert from plot area coordinates to graph (and hosting view) coordinates
dataPoint = [self.hostView.hostedGraph convertPoint:dataPoint   fromLayer:self.hostView.hostedGraph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];


// convert from hosting view coordinates to self.view coordinates (if needed)
dataPoint = [statsView convertPoint:dataPoint fromView:self.hostView];

NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: %@, y: %@", plotXvalue, plotYvalue);
NSLog(@"datapoint coordinates tapped: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(dataPoint));
```

this is the log that gets printed

barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex x: 2.002954100413836, y: 797.5011302303315

datapoint coordinates tapped: {442.67648899476842, 80323.113023033162}

**UPDATE**: It turns out I was calling this before the plot was completely setup, which is where the bogus numbers came from. Unfortunately, calling after it gets setup still doesn't give me the right answer. Much closer, but still wrong.

datapoint coordinates tapped: {109.55009099317836, 187.9865691006616}

**UPDATE 2**
as a hint, my X coordinates aren't proportional as i would expect
graph values of 3,6,9,12,15 give coordinates of 32, 71, 109, 147, 186

Comment: This Topic have got answers for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658209/core-plot-how-to-present-popover-from-a-bar-selected-by-the-user?rq=1

Comment: the one I linked in my question?

Comment: Is there a chance the graph hasn't been laid out fully when you call this code? If so, call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the graph first.